# Racket: define-type reference

Tags: reference, racket, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to use define-type to compile a suitable algebraic data type for references:

```
Books:                    Author. Title. Publisher, City Year
Articles from Magazines:  Author. Title. Name of Magazine, Year
Conference Contributions: Author. Title. Name of Conference. Publisher, City Year
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this problem. Though I do know the features of define-type and its difference to define-struct.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `define-type` refers to the `define-type` from `htdp2/abstraction`:

```
(define-type reference
   (book (author string?) (title string?) (publisher string?) (city string?) (year number?))
   (magazine-article (author string?) ...etc...)
   (conference-contribution (author string?) ...etc...))
```